# Cleaning up CSS in White Label environments

Tags: css, diff

I just inherited a project from a previous developer with 1 site that is white labelled to 4 other sites.

Unfortunately, each site has its own complete CSS file (site1.css, site2.css, ... etc). Clearly, each site CSS file was created by first copying the contents of the previous site into a new file and saving it.  I would say about 75% of the content overlaps across all CSS files.

I'd love to be able to create a "base.css" file, and then have each site have files that override this behaviour. I've tried diff tools, however, most of them don't respect CSS and just show the line differences (I'd obviously prefer to show selector differences).  The next step would be to create a base CSS where the CSS matches and then remove that base css from the remaining CSS files. Manually, it would be a very cumbersome task that is likely prone to errors since we're deal with 2K+ lines of CSS per file. I've tried other CSS tools such as http://prettydiff.com/ but it doesn't appear to be able to extract matching CSS. Am I running a fools errand or is this something feasible? Does a base.css file even make sense?

PS Also the other problem is that these are responsive CSS files that have size specific rules as well, such as:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {/*bunch of rules go here */}
```